# Is there a way to send message to chrome extension from backend server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm implementing lightweight "in-extension" support for my users. If a user asks a question or submits a query, how can I respond back to the user in the extension? It's given that auth is done and the user is logged in to the extension.

Comment: There's no special API, so you'll need to use some external server.